# HTML Check if a Cookie exists for another site

Tags: html, cookies

I am looking at Querying a cookie that is present on particular machines (it is an internal link that we use for authentication purposes).

This cookie has the domain ABC0X.companyname.com  Where X is any value from 1-5.  Is there a way that I can check to make sure that this cookie?

There is a virtual beer for anyone who can help :-)

Thanks,

Comment: Why you keep deleting and creating the same question everyday?

Comment: I don't believe so, cookies are (and should be) only available to the site by which they were set, according to the supplied path variable.